# Django is receiving image into a React Native FormData instance as an dict

Tags: python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, react-native-image-picker

I have a **`React Native`** app, there is a screen to upload a **`logo`** (an image). When the logo gets uploaded, **Django** should receive the image, save into an user row and create the file into local assets folder (as usual). The problem is, i don't even know if i am sending the data from React Native in a correct way, but **`Django REST API`** is receiving the image as an **`Python dict`**. I'm following the instructions from many other people, but still not working, here's how i load the logo into a React Native **FormData** instance:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('logo', {
  name: logo.fileName,
  uri: logo.uri,
  type: logo.type,
});
```

The **`logo`** variable is an **[Asset](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/blob/main/src/types.ts#L21)** instance, from **[react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker)** library.

And here, how Django receive the data, with **[pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)** (Python debugger):

[image]

For a better look:

```
{'_parts': [
  ['logo', {
    'name': 'logo.png',
    'uri': 'file:///data/user/0/com.micandidato/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_9b3907e0-3f13-4ad5-9ca9-13f491473440.png',
    'type': 'image/png'
  }]
]}
```

I'm pretty sure Django is not going to save this object as an image. The request method from React Native is **`PATCH`** (if relevant). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To append data (i.e. image) in FormData instance we have to pass the arguments like:

**#at FrontEnd**

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image',imageFileOrBlob,FileName*);
//rest of the code
```

> FileName is optional argument.

> The imageFileOrBlob in your case should be passed like `yourInputField.target.files[0]`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

**#at Django backEnd**

```
def myView(request):
  logo = request.FILES.get('image')
  #rest of the code
```

Comment: **REACT NATIVE** FormData class is not the same that browsers